# How can I get the main view, containing the partial view?

Tags: view, partial

I get partial view after form submission (it does not contain the main view). How can I get the main view, containing the partial view?

view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnBegin = "onBegin()", OnComplete = "onComplate()" }))
{
<div id="result"></div>
...
```

controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(model);
        }

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Index(mdl model)
{
...
return PartialView("_part", model);
}
```